# Shell Options in Deno

Tags: deno

Is there a way to read shell options in Deno? For example, to detect whether the current shell is in interactive mode, I would normally check to see if `$-` has an `i` in it:

```bash
if [[ $- == *i* ]]; then
  echo "interactive"
else
  echo "not interactive"
fi
```

<strike>I can of course use `Deno.run` to execute `['bash', '-c', 'echo $-']`, but is there any more elegant way to get access to this information?</strike>

EDIT: Actually running a `bash` command to print out the shell options doesn't appear to work for me either. The subprocess always reports itself as non-interactive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`Deno.isatty`](https://doc.deno.land/deno/stable/%7E/Deno.isatty) to make this determination. Example:

```ts
const isInteractive = Deno.isatty(Deno.stdin.rid);
console.log(`${isInteractive ? '' : 'not '}interactive`);
```